# Measurement error and type I. and type II. error

Tags: measurement-error, measurement, type-i-and-ii-errors

Is there a relationship between measurement error (1.) both systematic and random, (2.) systematic only and (3.) random only in terms of tendency of results of statistical tests to be biased towards type I. or type II. error?

Does anyone have tip for relevant literature on this topic?

//Edit: I was asked to clarify certain aspect of original question, therefore I add longer explanation via example: Let's have a repeating measurement of two continous variables (A and B), as a result I have a dataset of N observations and the two measured variables. For the sake of this example let's say I want to answer a question whether there exists stat. significant linear releationship (on given level of alpha) between A and B. Now, assuming ceteris paribus, can we tell whether or not will the result differ when I "add" systematic/random measurement error? If so, in what direct towards type I./II. error?

Comment: Could you explain what your key phrase "tendency of results of statistical tests to be biased towards type I. or type II. error" might possibly mean?  Please bear in mind that statistical tests will, *by design,* achieve a Type I error and the type II error is a function of the true state of affairs.  How does one define and assess "bias" in such a setting?

Comment: Let's have a repeating measurement of two continous variables (A and B), as a result I have a dataset of N observations and the two measured variables. For the sake of this example let's say I want to answer a question whether there exists stat. significant linear releationship (on given level of alpha) between A and B. Now assuming ceteris paribus, can we someone tell whether or not will the result differ when I "add" systematic/random measurement error? If so, in what direct towards type I./II. error?

Comment: That can be analyzed in detail when the measurement error applies only to the response variable.  When it applies to both the analysis is more delicate but possible.  Please, then, edit your post to include the information in your comment and to clarify the role played by measurement error.

Comment: I think that the question still needs work towards clarity, but it seems to me that the random error part might be excluded because an appropriate test will be expecting (based on) the random error properties of the data. Is that not the case?